# How do I include an @ sign within an NSString literal?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Searched around and didn't see an obvious answer.  Thanks in advance.

I simply want to append an @ sign at the end of an NSString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
NSString *myConstString = @"john@example.com";
```

And this will, too:

```
NSString *aString = ...;
NSString *myString = [aString stringByAppendingString: @"@"];
```

`@` is just a character which doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Thanks.  Will accept this answer. My problem was with surrounding logic.